# How to: Using Bootstrapv3 to create thumbnail layout with caption where caption is contained within the image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

expected result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeO84.jpg

progress:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/2Lptu49k/5/
```

Issue:
I can kind of see the narrow band of transparent area but I'm not able to fully cover the caption area. what gives. Appreciate your help!

Code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 tile">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12"  style="text-align:center">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row caption">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
            One
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
            Two
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 tile">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12"  style="text-align:center">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row caption">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
            One
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
            Two
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 tile">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12"  style="text-align:center">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row caption">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
            One
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
            Two
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-4 tile">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12"  style="text-align:center">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row caption">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
            One
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
            Two
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-sm-4 tile">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12"  style="text-align:center">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row caption">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
            One
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
            Two
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-sm-4 tile">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12"  style="text-align:center">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row caption">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
            One
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
            Two
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ignore the code details after the first row really. Once I get one tile right, I expect all of them to work.

I'm hoping that i can really use something simple to address this. I looked up similar questions and tried to put it all together but I think this falls a little short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there :). Using Bootstrap it is not that safe to add classes with a lot of style properties to a row or col- class. Split those `row caption` elements up:

```
<div class="caption">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
          One
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
          Two
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Added negative margin (margin:0; would be better, thinking about it) to `.caption` to counter the padding: [Check working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lptu49k/8/)

Comment: Thanks for your time on this! I have updated the same working fiddle slightly here. https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/2Lptu49k/9/ remind me again how I can add gaps between these 'tiles'. With that I'm all set with this.

Comment: Ah.. I see, just put a DIV with class tile inside the col-xs divs instead of combining the classes on one div. The gap is there now but not ‘visible’ I think

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this -

```css
.head {
  height: 70px;
  background: #CCC;
}
.tail {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="clearfix thumbnail">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row head">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            IMAGE
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row tail">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            Title
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            Desc
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="clearfix thumbnail">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row head">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            IMAGE
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row tail">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            Title
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            desc
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I altered your code a bit, but I believe is that what you were looking for. Press "full page" in a snippet to see results.

```css
.row {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.tile {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), url("http://www.sepeb.com/random-image/random-image-001.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

.caption {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #000 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: white;
}

.caption:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(152, 54, 55, 0.8);
}

.extend {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.extend:nth-of-type(3) {
    padding-right: 0;
}

.tile > .row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 extend">
                <div class="tile">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:center">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
                                One
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
                                Two
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 extend">
                <div class="tile">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:center">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
                                One
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
                                Two
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 extend">
                <div class="tile">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:center">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
                                One
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
                                Two
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-4 extend">
                <div class="tile">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:center">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
                                One
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
                                Two
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 extend">
                <div class="tile">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:center">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
                                One
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
                                Two
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 extend">
                <div class="tile">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:center">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
                                One
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center">
                                Two
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Yea, this is very close to what I was looking for. One last question- any idea why the caption shade doesn't work for me?

Comment: @zigzag Add it to element containing text, which is col-sm-6 in your example, but it would be better to wrap text inside more proper tag like that <div class="col-sm-6-><p>One</p></div>

Comment: Thanks. Tried that and here is where I'm stuck. https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/2Lptu49k/11/
Q: How do I get the caption area to float at the bottom of each image without that gap that's showing under it. I assume that's a bottom padding coming from somewhere but couldn't address it.

Comment: Nvm. Fixed it with this- https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/2Lptu49k/12/ Coders block tests my patience and brings me here too fast :)